# How to I read formula bar in excel sheet using php

Tags: php

I have some doubt for this Excel Reading. I Using Maths formula bar in my excel but I don't know how to read this value.

Please Help me This part

[image]

Comment: These fields probably have a name of their own, which you probably can see when going in developer mode. Please make the excel sheet available for testing purposes. Also, are you using PHPExcel? Which library are you using?

Comment: Also note that office products tend to use a LaTeX-like language for their formulas, so that you will probably get values like `\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}` (with [this output](http://oziris.ceu.hu/latex/40acc91772aeedbcecb7914258bfdcc4.png) )

Comment: Thank You Mr.JohannesB I'm Using                                                                                                         require_once 'Spreadsheet/Excel/reader.php';

$con=new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();

$con->read($target_file);     Is It Possible to read this file

Answer (score 0):

If your are using [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel), you can get answer from [PHPExcel docs](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki). For example 
if if is simple sum fromula, it seem like

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue(
        'B10',
        '=SUM(A10:B9)'
    );
```